# OAuth 2.0 How to validate token expiration date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am using MVC Web API inside MVC project. I used **SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider** to generate the token. and I used **AuthorizeForAPI** custom Attribute to valid the token. Everything is working great.
My question is how to validate token expiration date so if the the token has expired i will send a message from server tells the user that your token has  been expired

**This how i generate the token**

```
public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }


        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

        context.Validated(identity);

    }


    public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
        {
            context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

**And this how i valid the token**

```
public class AuthorizeForAPI : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        string AccessTokenFromRequest = "";
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization != null)
        {
            // get the access token
            AccessTokenFromRequest = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;

            var user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
            if (!user.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized user");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I strongly reccomend you use identities jwt middleware to genrate and validate your access token. It will take care of all nessesary checks. Besides: where do you generate a token? You only seem to set the identity.

Answer (score -1):

using

```
 AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(22), //22 day before expired
```

you can change it for minute , hours , etc in "timespan.from(this)"

Comment: First of all I would thank you for your help and time. 
My problem is not about Token Expire time . My problem about how to valid the token expire time, in other words, how to know if the token is expired or not, Because if the token is expired  i will  send message to client that your session is expired. Thank you

Comment: you want like realtime ?